# Creating Quiz: Why is it not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

The Quiz is perfectly showing in firefox and Chrome, just Safari seems to have some issues. It instantly shows the last test  instead of the first like chrome and firefox are doing. What am I doing wrong. (I am using Safari Version 8.0.2 (10600.2.5)).

```css
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  background: white;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300; }

input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0.1em solid #bbbbbb;
  background: none;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0 0.2em;
  font-family: Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none; }
  input[type=radio]:focus,
  input[type=checkbox]:focus {
    outline: 0;
    border-color: #335599; }

input[type=radio] {
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-clip: content-box; }
  input[type=radio]:checked {
    background-color: #44aacc; }

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  text-align: center; }

.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  background: white; }

.test a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #666666;
    color: white; }

.test a:hover {
    background: #4d4d4d; }

  .test .question {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed #666666; }

  .test .answer {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 4px solid white; }

    .test .answer:hover {
      border-color: #bbbbbb; }

  .test .test {
    transform: translate3d(150%, 0, 0);
    transition: transform 100ms;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0; }

  .test .false:checked + .answer {
    border-color: #dd4411; }

  .test .true:checked ~ .test {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="quiz_test.css" type="text/css">
        <meta>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>A simple Quiz in pure CSS</h1>
        <div class="test">
            <h3 class="question">1 + 2 = ?</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="1" id="1-1" class="false"> <label for="1-1" class="answer">12</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="1" id="1-2" class="true"> <label for="1-2" class="answer">3</label>
            <div class="test">
                <h3 class="question">red - green, orange - blue, yellow - ?</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="2" id="2-1" class="false"> <label for="2-1" class="answer">magenta</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="2" id="2-2" class="true"> <label for="2-2" class="answer">purple</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="2" id="2-3" class="false"> <label for="2-3" class="answer">cyan</label>
                <div class="test">
                    <h3 class="question">name the fish!</h3>
                    <input type="radio" name="3" id="3-1" class="true"> <label for="3-1" class="answer">shark</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="3" id="3-2" class="false"> <label for="3-2" class="answer">dolphin</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="3" id="3-3" class="false"> <label for="3-3" class="answer">whale</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="3" id="3-4" class="false"> <label for="3-4" class="answer">all of the above</label>
                    <div class="test">
                        <h1>YOU WIN!!!</h1>
                        <a href="">play again</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add some javascript too?

Comment: would be possible, but I don't understand javascript =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that webkit doesnt understand the transition and transform attributes without vendor prefixes. Copy every line of transition and transform and replace the duplicate with -webkit-transision and -webkit- transform.

```css
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  background: white;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300; }

input[type=radio],
input[type=checkbox] {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0.1em solid #bbbbbb;
  background: none;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0 0.2em;
  font-family: Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-appearance: none; }
  input[type=radio]:focus,
  input[type=checkbox]:focus {
    outline: 0;
    border-color: #335599; }

input[type=radio] {
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-clip: content-box; }
  input[type=radio]:checked {
    background-color: #44aacc; }

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  text-align: center; }

.test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  background: white; }

.test a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #666666;
    color: white; }

.test a:hover {
    background: #4d4d4d; }

  .test .question {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed #666666; }

  .test .answer {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 4px solid white; }

    .test .answer:hover {
      border-color: #bbbbbb; }

  .test .test {
    transform: translate3d(150%, 0, 0);
    transition: transform 100ms;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(150%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: transform 100ms;

    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0; }

  .test .false:checked + .answer {
    border-color: #dd4411; }

  .test .true:checked ~ .test {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="quiz_test.css" type="text/css">
        <meta>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>A simple Quiz in pure CSS</h1>
        <div class="test">
            <h3 class="question">1 + 2 = ?</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="1" id="1-1" class="false"> <label for="1-1" class="answer">12</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="1" id="1-2" class="true"> <label for="1-2" class="answer">3</label>
            <div class="test">
                <h3 class="question">red - green, orange - blue, yellow - ?</h3>
                <input type="radio" name="2" id="2-1" class="false"> <label for="2-1" class="answer">magenta</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="2" id="2-2" class="true"> <label for="2-2" class="answer">purple</label><br>
                <input type="radio" name="2" id="2-3" class="false"> <label for="2-3" class="answer">cyan</label>
                <div class="test">
                    <h3 class="question">name the fish!</h3>
                    <input type="radio" name="3" id="3-1" class="true"> <label for="3-1" class="answer">shark</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="3" id="3-2" class="false"> <label for="3-2" class="answer">dolphin</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="3" id="3-3" class="false"> <label for="3-3" class="answer">whale</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" name="3" id="3-4" class="false"> <label for="3-4" class="answer">all of the above</label>
                    <div class="test">
                        <h1>YOU WIN!!!</h1>
                        <a href="">play again</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

P.S. The snippet above doesn't run correctly in the preview box because some of stackoverflows css is interfering. It does however run correctly in the full page preview.

Comment: If you had read more carefully you would have seen the word "Chrome".Chrome is a webkit based browser so if it works on chrome it should work on safari

Comment: Well it DIDNT. Because first of all, chrome is not a webkit based anymore since it switched to blink back in 2013, and secondly, Safari treats vendor prefixes differently than cgrome and did so ever since.

Comment: Glad I could help. Accepting the answer would be appreciated. :)